# how to change read only to rewrite , sudo mount - o remount,rw/ not working

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sudo

I am trying to initiate a Ubuntu phone background change from the white origami background to a custom background.

I am using this `sudo` code:

```
sudo cp /home/phablet/Pictures/background.png/usr/share/unity8/graphics/phone_background.png
```

but I am getting a read only file error.

I need help how to change the read only file to rewritable.

Comment: This is a wrong command. There must be space between "from" and "to" path. Try this `sudo cp /home/phablet/Pictures/background.png  /usr/share/unity8/graphics/phone_background.png`

Comment: thank yes i tried that but still getting read only error.have you successfully changed the background before.

Comment: Look at the answer pls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct command must be

```
sudo cp /home/phablet/Pictures/background.png /usr/share/unity8/graphics/phone_background.png
```

You missed a space between "from" and "to" path.

The command in the question title is also wrong. It should be

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

I suggest to copy & paste commands, not to re-type them.

Entering commands like you do can lead to wiping everything from your phone.

Comment: thanx how can i learn these codes

Comment: These are not "codes" but bash commands. You can run `man cp` and `man mount` to see how to use them. `cp` copies files and there must be a space between from and to places.

Comment: @SavioLesperance If this answer solved your issue, then click the check sign at the left.

Comment: ok so i tried these bash command and it seemed to work in the terminal but i wasnt able to change the background. is the command a good one.

Comment: @SavioLesperance That's completely another issue. I know nothing about changing background in phones.

Comment: oh thanx anyway,so you dont own one.y not with your command knowledge u would be far.

Comment: @SavioLesperance You have an absolutely correct answer for your question. As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: ok i did and ,by any chance do you know how to reverse this command.thanx

Comment: @SavioLesperance It depends on did that file exist or not `/usr/share/unity8/graphics/phone_background.png`. If it did exist, than it is overwritten now. If not, you can remove it by `rm` command.

Comment: Well im not sure if that file existed or not if yes,forget about it that path was the wrong one and was able to change the background.Thanks so much dude.made my day